# Proplem with the infowindow in google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm getting some information from an API.
I'm calling the geocoder to get the point and then create my marker, with some text for the info windows.
My marker are placed on the map without a problem.

But when I click on the marker, it always display the same text.
I can't figure out how to 'pre-populate' the info window so when I click on the marker it displays the correct information ...

```
function createMarker(point, text) {
alert('point: ' + point + 'text: ' + text)
var html ="<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+ text + "<\/strong><\/div>";
//var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
    map: map,  
    position: point
});  

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
    content: html  
});  

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
    infowindow.open(map, marker);  
});  

return marker;
}
```

I hope it's clear enough!
I'm using the google API V3

Resolved it using the following code:

```
function createMarker(point, text) {
//var html ="<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+ text + "<\/strong><\/div>";
//var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
//    map: map,  
//    position: point
//});  

//infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
//  content: html  
//});  

//google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
//  infowindow.open(map, marker);

//});       
//return marker;

var title = 'LinkedIn Connection';
var html = "<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+ text + "<\/strong><\/div>";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title:title,
    content:html,
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    position:point
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    /* close the previous info-window */
    closeInfos();

    /* the marker's content gets attached to the info-window: */
    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});

    /* trigger the infobox's open function */
    info.open(map,this);

    /* keep the handle, in order to close it on next click event */
    infos[0]=info;

});
```

}

```
function closeInfos(){

   if(infos.length > 0){

  /* detach the info-window from the marker */
  infos[0].set("marker",null);

  /* and close it */
  infos[0].close();

  /* blank the array */
  infos.length = 0;
```

}
}

Comment: You can check the result in here: www.pukkafish.com/api/linkedin. You will need a linkedIn account.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createMarker(point, text) {
//var html ="<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+ text + "<\/strong><\/div>";
//var marker = new google.maps.Marker({    
//    map: map,  
//    position: point
//});  

//infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
//  content: html  
//});  

//google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
//  infowindow.open(map, marker);

//});       
//return marker;

var title = 'LinkedIn Connection';
var html = "<div class='infowindow'><strong>"+ text + "<\/strong><\/div>";

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    title:title,
    content:html,
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    position:point
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    /* close the previous info-window */
    closeInfos();

    /* the marker's content gets attached to the info-window: */
    var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: this.content});

    /* trigger the infobox's open function */
    info.open(map,this);

    /* keep the handle, in order to close it on next click event */
    infos[0]=info;

});
}

function closeInfos(){

   if(infos.length > 0){

  /* detach the info-window from the marker */
  infos[0].set("marker",null);

  /* and close it */
  infos[0].close();

  /* blank the array */
  infos.length = 0;
} }
```